# Operating effectively on one monitor in a split-monitor setup?

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors

I have a dual-monitor setup but sometimes use one of the monitors for my game system. This leaves a single monitor (the one without the start menu) for my use.

Apart from turning the primary monitor back on or changing display settings, are there ways to manage windows and be able to "grab" windows from the other monitor?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, I think you run a game on monitor 1 (with the start button and taskbar) and then monitor 2 is completely blank and you can't get things without minimizing your game?
I have a dual monitor setup and this is what I do:

Displayfusion is a great program and can extend the taskbar menu or duplicate the start button.  I mainly got it to have 2 different backgrounds in win 7.  Which leads to the next solution, Win8 is set up much better for dual monitors. Also it [display fusion] can bypass start screen on boot so really my win8 is now a better win 7.  Good luck!

Comment: +1 for mentioning DisplayFusion. I use that too, does the job perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool like [ZBar](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/zbar/) to move applications and task bar entries between monitors. It provides several keyboard shortcuts to speed up switching back and forth.

Another tool to switch the primary monitor is [here](http://www.syaeger.com/PCUtils/MakePrimaryMonitor.html). You can define a desktop icon with a keyboard shortcut to achieve a quick monitor toggle.